# How do I add a header to a CXF WebClient request?

Tags: java, rest, curl, cxf, cxfrs

I want to do the equivalent of this curl command:

```
curl --header "Access-Control-Request-Headers: foo, bar" url
```

The CXF API gives the impression that this is straight forward, but I can't get it to work.  Here's my code:

```
List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<>();
providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
WebClient client = org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/app/v2/preview", providers).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = client.header("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "foo, bar").get();
```

The difference is, if I hit a breakpoint on my server, the curl request has this header, and the `WebClient` command doesn't.  Is this a bug?  If not, what am I doing wrong?

I'm using the cxf-bundle-minimal-2.7.10 version of the web client.